# Troubleshooting JVM CPU spikes

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage, tcserver

We're seeing an interesting (though quite severe) issue with one of our application servers: at a certain point in time, the CPU usage of the JVM running our web applications starts rising and keeps on rising until the applications eventually slow down to a crawl. The only way to fix it is to restart the Application server software.

- Application server: Spring tc Server (as the servers are hosted elsewhere, I currently do not know the exact version)
- Applications: relatively standard Spring 3 web applications (we do use an in-JVM EHCache though)

This brings me to a simple question; what can we do to troubleshoot this?

I have considered using VisualVM (or some other JVM monitoring tool), but the best they can do  - in this particular case - is give me a thread dump, which still will not tell me what is eating up all the CPU time (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find out what it is doing?  A common cause of this problem is running low on free memory.  If this is not the cause, a CPU profiler is needed.  VisualVM comes free with the JDK and can do both for you.

> only you can't profile the application all the time

When this is happening you can do an ad hoc profiling by calling `jstack` multiple times a few second apart.  You can use `diff` of the stack traces to help you can find the thread which are likely to be busy and consuming CPU.

Comment: Memory consumption was our first guess but it was in fact normal (with plenty to spare). Using a profiler is a good suggestion, only you can't profile the application all the time (this hasn't happened for 2 weeks until now).

Answer (score 5):

The CPU consuming threads are basically the stuck or hogging threads or the GC activities if the Full GC is being performed.

If you are on a unix based environment, then executing the below will give a preview of the utilization of the JVM threads. (PID is the process id for the jvm).

```
prstat -L -p <PID>
```

A threaddump (kill -3 ) can be subsequently taken and then the prstat and the threadump can be co-related to find which threads are using high CPU.

The nid in the thread dump  corresponds to the HEX value of the LWPID in the output of prstat.

```
Eg: LWPID = java/75 corresponds to nid = 0X4B
```

Once the CPU consuming threads are found in the thread dump, the pointer to where the investigation should start will be available.

Additionally, running a profiler eg: Jprofiler will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for high CPU usage could be because a Full GC is being performed.
You can look here http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/ to understand how to monitor GC in a jvm.

If there is no GC activity, you need to take a thread dump when your CPU usage crosses a certain threshold using jstack multiple times a few seconds (5-10) apart. You can achieve this through a background process which monitors the CPU usage of the process running the jvm using the Unix top command.

Once the thread dumps are available you can run them through a profiler like VisualVM or Samurai that will help you narrow down to the root cause