# What could cause global Tomcat/JVM slowdown?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat7

I'm experiencing a strange but severe problem running several (about 15) instances of a Java EE-ish web applications (Hibernate 4+Spring+Quartz+JSF+Facelets+Richfaces) on Tomcat 7/Java 7.

The system runs just fine, but after a greatly variyng amount of time all instances of the application at the same time suddenly suffer from rising response times. Basically the application still works, but the response times are about three times higher.

This are two diagrams displaying the response time of two certain short workflows/actions (log in, access list of seminars, ajax-refresh this list, log out; the lower line is just the request time for the ajax refresh) of two example instances of the application:

[image: Response times of context 1]
[image: Resoinse times of context 2]

As you can see both instances of the application "explode" at the exact same time and stay slow. After restarting the server everything's back to normal. All the instances of the application "explode" simultaneously.

We're storing the session data to a database and use this for clustering. We checked session size and number and both are rather low (meaning that on other servers with other applications we sometimes have larger and more sessions). The other Tomcat in the cluster usually stays fast for some more hours and after this random-ish amount of time it also "dies". We checked the heap sizes with jconsole and the main heap stays between 2.5 and 1 GB size, db connection pool is basically full of free connections, as well as the thread pools. Max heap size is 5 GB, there's also plenty of perm gen space available. The load is not especially high; there's just about 5% load on the main CPU. The server does not swap. It's also no hardware issue as we additionally deployed the applications to a VM where the problems remain the same.

I don't know where to look anymore, I am out of ideas. Has someone an idea where to look?

### 2013-02-21 Update: New Data!

I added two more timing traces to the application. As for the measurement: the monitoring system calls a servlet that performs two tasks, measures execution time for each on the server and writes the time taken as response. These values are logged by the monitoring system.

I have several interesting new facts: a hot redeployment of the application causes this single instance on the current Tomcat to go nuts. This also seems to affect raw CPU calculation performance (see below). This individual-context-explosion is different from the overall-context-explosion that occurs randomly.

Now for some data:

[image: Diagram 3]
[image: Diagram 4]

First the individual lines:

1. Light blue is total execution time of a small workflow (details see above), measured on the client
2. Red is "part" of light blue and is the time taken to perform a special step of that workflow, measured on the client
3. Dark blue is measured in the application and consists of reading a list of entities from the DB through Hibernate and iterating over that list, fetching lazy collections and lazy entities.
4. Green is a small CPU benchmark using floating point and integer operations. As far as I see no object allocation, so no garbage.

Now for the individual stages of explosion: I marked each image with three black dots. The first one is a "small" explostion in more or less only one application instance - in Inst1 it jumps (especially visible in the red line), while Inst2 below more or less stays calm.

After this small explosion the "big bang" occurs and all application instances on that Tomcat explode (2nd dot). Note that this explosion affects all high level operations (request processing, DB access), but **not** the CPU benchmark. It stays low in both systems.

After that I hot-redeployed Inst1 by touching the context.xml file. As I said earlier this instance goes from exploded to completely devestated now (the light blue line is out of the chart - it is at about 18 secs). Note how a) this redeployment does not affect Inst2 at all and b) how the raw DB access of Inst1 is also not affected - but how the CPU suddenly *seems to have become slower!*. This is crazy, I say.

**Update of update**
The leak prevention listener of Tomcat does not whine about stale ThreadLocals or Threads when the application is undeployed. There obviously seems to be some cleanup problem (which is I assume not directly related to the Big Bang), but Tomcat doesn't have a hint for me.

### 2013-02-25 Update: Application Environment and Quartz Schedule

The application environment is not very sophisticated. Network components aside (I don't know enough about those) there's basically one application server (Linux) and two database servers (MySQL 5 and MSSQL 2008). The main load is on the MSSQL server, the other one merely serves as a place to store the sessions.

The application server runs an Apache as a load balancer between two Tomcats. So we have two JVMs running on the same hardware (two Tomcat *instances*). We use this configuration not to actually balance load as the application server is capable of running the application just fine (which it did for years now) but to enable small application updates without downtime. The web application in question is deployed as separate *contexts* for different customers, about 15 contexts per Tomcat. (I seemm to have mixed up "instances" and "contexts" in my posting - here in the office they're often used synonymously and we usually magically know what the colleague is talking about. My bad, I'm really sorry.)

**To clarify the situation with better wording**: the diagrams I posted show response times of two different contexts of the same application on the same JVM. The Big Bang affects all contexts on one JVM but doesn't happen on the other one (the order in which the Tomcats explode is random btw). After hot-redeployment one context on one Tomcat instance goes nuts (with all the funny side effects, like seemingly slower CPU for that context).

The overall load on the system is rather low. It's an internal core business related software with about 30 active users simultaneously. Application specific requests (server touches) are currently at about 130 per minute. The number of single requests are low but the requests itself often require several hundred selects to the database, so they're rather expensive. But usually everything's perfectly acceptable. The application also does not create large infinite caches - some lookup data is cached, but only for a short amount of time.

Above I wrote that the servers where capable of running the application just fine for several years. I know that the best way to find the problem would be to find out exactly when things went wrong for the first time and see what has been changed in this timeframe (in the application itself, the associated libraries or infrastructure), however the problem is that we don't know when the problems first occured. Just let's call that suboptimal (in the sense of absent) application monitoring... :-/

We ruled out some aspects, but the application has been updated several times during the last months and thus we e.g. cannot simply deploy an older version. The largest update that wasn't feature change was a switch from JSP to Facelets. But still, "something" must be the cause of all the problems, yet I have no idea why Facelets for instance should influence pure DB query times.

#### Quartz

As for the Quartz schedule: there's a total of 8 jobs. Most of them run only once per day and have to do with large volume data synchronization (absolutely not "large" as in "big data large"; it's just more than the averate user sees through his usual daily work). However, those jobs of course run at night and the problems occur during daytime. I omit a detailled job listing here (if beneficial I can provide more details of course). The jobs' source code has not been altered during the last months. I already checked whether the explosions align with the jobs - yet the results are inconclusive at best. I'd actually say that they don't align, but as there are several jobs that run every minute I can't rule it out just yet. The acutal jobs that run every minute are pretty low-weight in my opinion, they usually check if data is available (in different sources, DB, external systems, email account) and if so write it to the DB or push it to another system.

However I'm currently enabling logging of indivdual job execution so that I can exactly see start and end timestamp of each single job execution. Perhaps this provides more insight.

### 2013-02-28 Update: JSF Phases and Timing

I manually added a JSF phae listener to the application. I executed a sample call (the ajax refresh) and this is what I've got (left: normal running Tomcat instance, right: Tomcat instance after Big Bang - the numbers have been taken almost simultaneously from both Tomcats and are in milliseconds):

1. RESTORE_VIEW: 17 vs 46
2. APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES: 170 vs 486
3. PROCESS_VALIDATIONS: 78 vs 321
4. UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES: 75 vs 307
5. RENDER_RESPONSE: 1059 vs 4162

The ajax refresh itself belongs to a search form and its search result. There's also another delay between the application's outmost request filter and web flow starts its work: there's a `FlowExecutionListenerAdapter` that measures time taken in certain phases of web flow. This listener reports 1405 ms for "Request submitted" (which is as far as I know the first web flow event) out of a total of 1632 ms for the complete request on an un-exploded Tomcat, thus I estimate about 200ms overhead.
But on the exploded Tomcat it reports 5332 ms for request submitted (meaning all JSF phases happen in those 5 seconds) out of a total request duration of 7105ms, thus we're up to almost 2 seconds overhead for everything outside of web flow's request submitted.
Below my measurement filter the filter chain contains a `org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter`, then the Spring servlet is called.

### 2013-06-05 Update: All the stuff going on in the last weeks

A small and rather late update... the application performance still sucks after some time and the behaviour remains erratic. Profiling did not help much yet, it just generated an enormous amount of data that's hard to dissect. (Try poking around in performance data on or profile a production system... sigh) We conducted several tests (ripping out certain parts of the software, undeploying other applications etc.) and actually had some improvements that affect the whole application. The default flush mode of our `EntityManager` is `AUTO` and during view rendering lots of fetches and selects are issued, always including the check whether flushing is neccesary.
So we built a JSF phase listener that sets the flush mode to `COMMIT` during `RENDER_RESPONSE`. This improved overall performance *a lot* and seems to have mitigated the problems somewhat.

Yet, our application monitoring keeps yielding completely insane results and performance on some contexts on some tomcat instances. Like an action that should finish in under a second (and that actually does it after deployment) and that now takes more than four seconds. (These numbers are supported by manual timing in the browsers, so it's not the monitoring that causes the problems).

See the following picture for example:
[image: Diagram]

This diagram shows two tomcat instances running the same context (meaning same db, same configuration, same jar). Again the blue line is the amount of time taken by pure DB read operations (fetch a list of entities, iterate over them, lazily fetch collections and associated data). The turquoise-ish and red line are measured by rendering several views and doing an ajax refresh, respectively. The data rendered by two of the requests in turquoise-ish and red is mostly the same as is queried for the blue line.

Now around 0700 on instance 1 (right) there's this huge increase in pure DB time which seems to affect actual render response times as well, but only on tomcat 1. Tomcat 0 is largely unaffected by this, so it cannot be caused by the DB server or network with both tomcats running on the same physical hardware. It has to be a software problem in the Java domain.

During my last tests I found out something interesting: All responses contain the header "X-Powered-By: JSF/1.2, JSF/1.2". Some (the redirect responses produced by WebFlow) even have "JSF/1.2" three times in there.
I traced down the code parts that set those headers and the first time this header is set it's caused by this stack:

```
... at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.FilterServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:384)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.<init>(ExternalContextImpl.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:108)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContext.newInstance(FlowFacesContext.java:81)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener.requestSubmitted(FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener.java:37)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionListeners.fireRequestSubmitted(FlowExecutionListeners.java:89)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:255)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
... several thousands ;) more
```

The second time this header is set by

```
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.FilterServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:384)   
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.<init>(ExternalContextImpl.java:131)   
at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:108)   
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FacesContextHelper.getFacesContext(FacesContextHelper.java:46)   
at org.springframework.faces.richfaces.RichFacesAjaxHandler.isAjaxRequestInternal(RichFacesAjaxHandler.java:55)   
at org.springframework.js.ajax.AbstractAjaxHandler.isAjaxRequest(AbstractAjaxHandler.java:19)   
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.createServletExternalContext(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:216)   
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:182)   
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)   
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)   
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)   
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)   
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)   
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)   
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
```

I have no idea if this could indicate a problem, but I did not notice this with other applications that are running on any of our servers, so this might as well provide some hints. I really have no idea what that framework code is doing (admittedly I did not dive into it yet)... perhaps someone has an idea? Or am I running into a dead end?

#### Appendix

My CPU benchmark code consists of a loop that calculates Math.tan and uses the result value to modify some fields on the servlet instance (no volatile/synchronized there), and secondly performs several raw integer calcualations. This is not severly sophisticated, I know, but well... it seems to show something in the charts, however I am not sure what it shows. I do the field updates to prevent HotSpot from optimizing away all my precious code ;)

```
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        double tan = Math.tan(i);
        if (tan < 0) {
            this.l1++;
        } else {
            this.l2++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 7500; i++) {
        int n = i;
        while (n != 1) {
            this.steps++;
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n /= 2;
            } else {
                n = n * 3 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // This execution time is written to the client.
    time2 = System.nanoTime() - time2;
```

Comment: How do you measure response time? Could it be that the problem lies outside of your instance, for example caused by a router that doesn't handle connections as fast as it used to? You could try to measure response time when connecting from the same machine the instance runs on (from a console) once such a slowdown occurs to make sure it isn't caused by network problems.

Comment: You're convinced it's not GC? What do the mark and sweep stats look like?

Comment: @Axel I don't think that it's an infrastructure problem as the other Tomcat running on the same hardware still shows normal response times for some time after the first one starts showing problems

Comment: What are your exact versions of Tomcat and the associated JRE?  I ask because I recently answered the following linked question and want to make sure you are not also a victim of it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902928/why-does-the-jvm-of-these-tomcat-servers-perform-a-full-gc-hourly/14903004#14903004

Comment: @JoshDM java -version outputs `java version "1.7.0_13" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`, Tomcat is 7.0.27. I don't think that a possible hourly full GC would cause permanent slowdowns, especially with the GC stats looking OK. However, I have some new data to show - see my edit above that I'll start now...

Comment: Well then, considering you're one Tomcat deployment lower than said recommended deployment, it might not cause you any harm to set your `org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener` to have `gcDaemonProtection="false"` and see what happens.

Comment: @JoshDM Unfortunately but not totally unexpected this did not help, but thanks anyway... we're currently fiddling around with the other Leak-Prevention-Settings, perhaps there's another currently hidden leak or something.

Comment: I tossed a bounty on this; you're providing a lot of detail, so it's worth it and this question isn't visible enough, in my opinion.  I think it is time that you elaborate on your applications, including providing details regarding your Quartz timers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Solution

Increase the maximum size of the Code Cache:

```
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
```

## Background

We are using ColdFusion 10 which runs on Tomcat 7 and Java 1.7.0_15. Our symptoms were similar to yours. Occasionally the response times and the CPU usage on the server would go up by a lot for no apparent reason. It seemed as if the CPU got slower. The only solution was to restart ColdFusion (and Tomcat).

### Initial analysis

I started by looking at the memory usage and the garbage collector log. There was nothing there that could explain our problems.

My next step was to schedule a heap dump every hour and to regularly perform sampling using VisualVM. The goal was to get data from before and after a slowdown so that it could be compared. I managed to get accomplish that.

There was one function in the sampling that stood out: get() in coldfusion.runtime.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap. A lot of time was spent in it after the slowdown compared to very little before. I spent some time on understanding how the function worked and developed a theory that maybe there was a problem with the hash function resulting in some huge buckets. Using the heap dumps I was able to see that the largest buckets only contained 6 elements so I discarded that theory.

### Code Cache

I finally got on the right track when I read "Java Performance: The Definitive Guide". It has a chapter on the JIT Compiler which talks about the Code Cache which I had not heard of before.

### Compiler disabled

When monitoring the number of compilations performed (monitored with jstat) and the size of the Code Cache (monitored with Memory Pools plugin of VisualVM) I saw that the size increased up to the maximum size (which is 48 MB by default in our environment -- the default varies depending on Java version and Java compiler). When the Code Cache became full the JIT Compiler was turned off. I have read that "CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled." should be printed when that happens but I did not see that message; maybe the version we are using does not have that message. I know that the compiler was turned off because the number of compilations performed stopped increasing.

### Deoptimization continues

The JIT Compiler can deoptimize previously compiled functions which will caues the function to be executed by the interpreter again (unless the function is replaced by an improved compilation). The deoptimized function can be garbage collected to free up space in the Code Cache.

For some reason functions continued to be deoptimized even though nothing was compiled to replace them. More and more memory would become available in the Code Cache but the JIT Compiler was not restarted.

I never had -XX:+PrintCompilation enabled when we experience a slowdown but I am quite sure that I would have seen either ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(), or a function that it depends on, be deoptimized at that time.

### Result

We have not seen any slowdowns since we increased the maximum size of the Code Cache to 256 MB and we have also seen a general performance improvement. There is currently 110 MB in our Code Cache.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this was the fix.

Comment: Solved the issue for me as well. A good parameter to be aware of regardless.

Comment: This solved it, thanks. It's rather strange that the JVM does not tell one about this pretty important event in a less overlookable way... if it actually does, that is. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

First, let me say that you have done an excellent job grabbing detailed *facts* about the problem; I really like how you make it clear what you know and what you are speculating - it really helps.

**EDIT 1** Massive edit after the update on context vs. instance

We can rule out:

- GCs (that would affect the CPU benchmark service thread and spike the main CPU)
- Quartz jobs (that would either affect both Tomcats or the CPU benchmark)
- The database (that would affect both Tomcats)
- Network packet storms and similar (that would affect both Tomcats)

I believe that you are suffering from is an increase in **latency** somewhere in your JVM. Latency is where a thread is waiting (synchronously) for a response from somewhere - it's increased your servlet response time but at no cost to the CPU. Typical latencies are caused by:

- Network calls, including

  - JDBC
  - EJB or RMI
  - JNDI
  - DNS
  - File shares
- Disk reading and writing
- Threading

  - Reading from (and sometimes writing to) queues
  - `synchronized` method or block
  - `futures`
  - `Thread.join()`
  - `Object.wait()`
  - `Thread.sleep()`

**Confirming that the problem is latency**

I suggest using a commercial profiling tool. I like [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html, 15 day trial version available) but [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/features/) is also recommended by the StackOverflow community. In this discussion I will use JProfiler terminology.

Attach to the Tomcat process while it is performing fine and get a feel for how it looks under normal conditions. In particular, use the high-level JDBC, JPA, JNDI, JMS, servlet, socket and file probes to see how long the JDBC, JMS, etc operations take ([screencast](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2012/01/profiling-jpa-hibernate/). Run this again when the server is exhibiting problems and compare. Hopefully you will see what precisely has been slowed down. In the product screenshot below, you can see the SQL timings using the JPA Probe:

[image: JPA hotspots]
<sub>(source: [ej-technologies.com](http://static-aws.ej-technologies.com/SanJPN2pU9HB3g30N03BZsAwd77YzUtpXAsZoe9VUCi.png))</sub>

However it's possible that the probes did not isolate the issue - for example it might be some  threading issue. Go to the Threads view for the application; this displays a running chart of the states of each thread, and whether it is executing on the CPU, in an `Object.wait()`, is waiting to enter a `synchronized` block or is waiting on network I/O . When you know which thread or threads is exhibiting the issue, go to the CPU views, select the thread and use the thread states selector to immediately drill down to the expensive methods and their call stacks. [Screencast](([screencast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/07/thread-states-in-cpu-profiling-views.html)). You will be able to drill up into your application code.

This is a call stack for runnable time:

[image]

And this is the same one, but showing network latency:

[image]

When you know *what* is blocking, hopefully the path to resolution will be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However I seem to not have made the actual system configuration clear enough. I'm sorry :(! The JVM instances are independend and clustering works by a sticky-session-loadbalancer in apache and using a MySQL DB as session storage. This allows deployment of minor updates without downtime and suffices the actual user load.

Comment: @chammp: No problems  -  I had read that but there may still be JGroups on in your environment, or there may be other network services or network issues. Sometimes there can be packetstorms because of something as simple as a frayed cat5 cable. Running ntop should help check if this is the problem

Comment: @chammp: I've read the new configuration details and updated my answer with a description of how to get to the bottom of what is slowing down the responses.

Comment: Thanks... we hooked up Yourkit to the JVMs. Now it's time to wait for the Big Bang and then we can analyse what's going wrong... hopefully ;)

Comment: Good luck. If you need help with the analysis, I'm online for another 2.5 hours, so you could set up a chat session here on S.O.

Comment: Sadly till now we weren't able to extract any useful data out of Yourkit. Full CPU tracing is impossible (request times would go up to hours, at least that's what I estimate) and the situation did not occur. Today perhaps...

Comment: No worries - you're right, don't trace cpu *until* the performance issue occurs.  Then,  you only need a minute or so of **sampling**. Just remember to save the data so you can restart the server and analyse at you leisure.  Good luck.

Comment: Even though the issue remains unresolved at this time, which most items requiring monitoring might, as the most comprehensive and still-monitored answer, I'm awarding the bounty here.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem, running on Java 1.7.0_u101 (one of Oracle's supported versions, since the latest public JDK/JRE 7 is 1.7.0_u79), running on G1 garbage collector. I cannot tell if the problem appears in other Java 7 versions or with other GCs.

Our process was Tomcat running Liferay Portal (I believe the exact version of Liferay is of no interest here).

This is the behavior we observed: using a -Xmx of 5GB, the inital Code Cache pool size right after startup ranged at about 40MB. After a while, it dropped to about 30MB (which is kind of normal, since there is a lot of code running during startup which will be never executed again, so it is expected to be evicted from the cache after some time). We observed that there was some JIT activity, so the JIT actually populated the cache (comparing to the sizes I am mentioning later, it seems that the small cache size relative to the overall heap size places stringent requirements on the JIT, and this makes the latter evict the cache rather nervously). However, after a while, no more compilations ever took place, and the JVM got painfully slow. We had to kill our Tomcats every now and then to get back adequate performance, and as we added more code to our portal, the problem got worse and worse (since the Code Cache got saturated more quickly, I guess).

It seems that there are several bugs in JDK 7 JVM that cause it to not restart the JIT (look at this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/why_do_i_get_message), even in JDK 7, after an emergency flush (the blog mentions Java bugs 8006952, 8012547, 8020151 and 8029091).

This is why increasing manually the Code Cache to a level where an emergency flush is unlikely to ever occur "fixes" the issue (I guess this is the case with JDK 7).

In our case, instead of trying to adjust the Code Cache pool size, we chose to upgrade to Java 8. This seems to have fixed the issue. Also, the Code Cache now seems to be quite larger (startup size gets about 200MB, and cruising size gets to about 160MB). As it is expected, after some idling time, the cache pool size drops, to get up again if some user (or robot, or whatever) browses our site, causing more code to be executed.

I hope you find the above data helpful.

Forgot to say: I found the exposition, the supporting data, the infering logic and the conclusion of this post very, very helpful. Thank you, really!

Answer (score 1):

> Has someone an idea where to look?

1. Issue could be out of Tomcat/JVM- do you have some batch job which kicks in and stress the shared resource(s) like a common database?
2. Take a thread dump and see what the java processes are doing when application response time explodes?
3. If you are using Linux, use a tool like **strace** and check what is java process doing.

Comment: I suspect the issue to be inside the running JVM (Tomcat) as the other instance usually remains fast for some amount of time and they run on the same hardware and after tomcat restart the response times go down immediately.

Comment: As for the thread dumps: all ajp-pool-threads are in `RUNNABLE` at `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0` most of the time, the background threads of quartz are in `TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)`, and the http-bio-pool-threads usually are in `WAITING (parking)` and waiting for their `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`. If a thread is inside the actual application stack, there doesn't seem to be a pattern, at least I don't recognize one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked JVM GC times? Some GC algorithms might 'pause' the application threads and increase the response time.

You can use [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) utility to monitor garbage collection statistics:

```
jstat -gcutil <pid of tomcat> 1000 100
```

Above command would print GC statistics on every 1 second for 100 times. Look at the FGC/YGC columns, if the number keeps raising, there is something wrong with your GC options.

You might want to switch to CMS GC if you want to keep response time low:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

You can check more GC options [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors.selecting).

Comment: They rise, but slowly. Every now and then a GC kicks in and moves bytes from eden to s0/s1, but the overall data seems OK:

`  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 31.98   0.00  75.70  28.22  94.74   1934  101.919    24   48.093  150.012
 31.98   0.00  85.00  28.22  94.74   1934  101.919    24   48.093  150.012
 31.98   0.00  87.73  28.22  94.74   1934  101.919    24   48.093  150.012
 31.98   0.00  92.82  28.22  94.74   1934  101.919    24   48.093`

Comment: (Can't show a table in the comment): only as E goes up from 92.82 to 98.79 and then down to 0.82, while in the last step S1 goes up from 0.00 to 99.95, GCT goes from 150.012 to 150.068. This happens about every 50 seconds. For example.

Comment: @chammp Your data looks good. To make sure, are you gathering the statistic after things went wrong?

Comment: @chammp How do you measure the response time? You might want to enable tomcat access log and `%D` option to print out the _time taken to process the request_ for every request URL. The configuration reference can be found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve).

Comment: We measure the response times at two different places: first there's a monitoring system that runs on another server and logs the total roundrip times for each request, and secondly I added a filter to web.xml that measures each application-specific request (so we don't measure static resource requests), and the numbers in both are basically the same.

Comment: @chammp could you please confirm my previous comment?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot... yes, I measured those numbers during the slowdown right before a Tomcat restart and to make sure also executed the same command on the second Tomcat instance and both looked pretty identical. In terms of relative numbers, that is... absolut numbers like GCT of course differed due to differences in actual uptime.

Comment: @chammp then you might need use profile tools to narrow down the hunting zone: [HouseMD](https://github.com/zhongl/HouseMD) or [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace). For example, the `ajax refresh` request requires two method invocations, and you can measure the execution time of each methods at runtime using the tools. Hopefully you will find the bottleneck. Note there is some overhead added by the profile tool so you might not get the accurate execution time, but you can consider the relative numbers.

Comment: Yes, I thought about profiling and already added a little manual profiling to some parts of the application, but the results where inconclusive at best. We might have to try a "real" profiler, however this would most likely really kill performance. I added two more timing benchmarks, perhaps this allows to rule out some more parts of the application (pure CPU time and DB access through Hibernate). Or it doesn't help as so many other measurements in the past did ;) We'll see...

Answer (score 1):

What happens after your app is performing slow for a while, does it get back to performing well?
If so then I would check if there is any activity that is not related to your app taking place at this time.
Something like an antivirus scan or a system/db backup.

If not then I would suggest running it with a profiler (JProfiler, yourkit, etc.) this tools can point you to your hotspots very easily.

Comment: Sometimes after several hours the response times get better. "Better" meaning a reduction of say 5%. This is also pretty random. Interestingly enough the last time I observed this at this time total request and ajax response time went down a little while pure data base query time increased...

Answer (score 0):

You are using Quartz, which manages timed processes, and this seems to take place at particular times.

Post your Quartz schedule and let us know if that aligns, and if so, you can determine which internal application process may be kicking off to consume your resources.

Alternately, it is possible a portion of your application code has finally been activated and decides to load data to the memory cache.  You're using Hibernate; check the calls to your database and see if anything coincides.

Comment: Thank you! I added a few more lines to my posting above. In essence the jobs running during day time seem harmless, but I'll add more logging to get more insight.

Comment: I see in yesterday's update that your application changed their forward-facing design from JSP to Facelets.  Has this changed the positioning of your database requests from prior to the View to be incorporated in your View?  If so, a client http request might be partially loaded and pending for additional database requests to complete.

Comment: Prior JSF/Facelets it was JSF/JSP, so that was not a complete paradigm shift. Even then I don't understand why suddenly the exact same requests should take longer than before. Fun fact: the application still works as it should, so even if it is some kind of timeout/internal thread blocking it mysteriously is resolved.